# Как остановить поток при комбинации?

Tags: java

Привет всем. Подскажите, как остановить потоки при комбинации клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

```
class Q {
int n;
boolean valueSet = false;

synchronized int get() { 
    while(!valueSet)
    try {
        wait () ;
    } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
        System.out.println("InterruptedException перехвачено");
    }
    System.out.println("Получено: " + n) ; 
    valueSet = false;
    notify(); 
    return n;
}

synchronized void put(int n) { 
    while(valueSet)
    try { 
        wait();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
        System.out.println("InterruptedException перехвачено");
    }
    this.n = n; 
    valueSet = true;
    System.out.println("Отправлено: " + n); notify();
}
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
Q q;
Producer(Q q) { 
    this.q = q;
    new Thread(this, "Поставщик").start() ;
}
public void run() { 
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        q.put(i++);
    }
}
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Q q;
    Consumer(Q q) { 
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Потребитель").start();
    }

public void run() {
    while(true) {
        q. get();
    }
    }
}

class PC { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Q q = new Q ();
    new Producer(q);
    new Consumer(q);
    System.out.println("Для останова нажмите Control-C.");
}

 boolean pushButton;
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F9) {
            pushButton=true;
            System.out.println("NAHZ");
        }
        else pushButton=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Добавить для каждого класса булеану состояния, и выполнять поток, пока ее значение равно истине.
2. Добавить листенер, который будет ловить нажатие клавиш.
3. Как только нажатая комбинация клавиш будет эквивалента заданной вами, то сменить значение булеаны на ложь.

Comment: Допустим есть слушатель     
  boolean pushButton;
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F9) {
                pushButton=true;
                System.out.println("NAHZ");
            }
            else pushButton=false;
        }
Но куда его вставлять? Я нажимаю F9 - сообщение не пишет

Comment: Добавьте дополнением код листенера в ваш вопрос, я думаю проблема в том, что Listener ни на чем не закреплен.

Comment: Добавил. Я новичок просто, и не знаю как решить мою задачу. Весь код брал из учебника

Comment: Смотрите. Булеаны состояния нужно вешать на классы, которые запускаются во внешних потоках (у каждого класса должен быть член класса типа булеаны), в вашем случае у Consumer и Procuder. И изменить для них методы на `public void run() { while (новая ваша булеана) }`. И ваш листенер должен на что-то вешаться. Поскольку у вас консольное приложение, то нужно использовать `BufferedReader`, который будет читать информацию с потока `System.in`

Comment: И поскольку вы новичок, вам будет очень полезно прочесть тогда документацию, особенно тему, которая касается многопоточности.

Comment: Т.е. написать внутри class Producer implements Runnable { } и class Сonsumer implements Runnable { }  public void run() { while (новая ваша булеана) } ??? Или может внутри этих классов в public void run() { }, кот. уже имеется сделать цикл do while? Т.е. выполнять счет до тех пор, пока не будут нажаты ctrl + C?

Comment: Вам нужно к классу Procuder и Consumer добавить член класса типа булеаны, например в классе Procuder добавится поле `boolean status = true;`, после чего вы используете эту булеану в ранее написанном вами методе `run()`, заменяя `while(this)` на `while(status)`. А уже потом в листенере меняете, при нажатии клавиш меняете значение `status = false;`. Поскольку у вас приложение консольное, то listener реализовывается через `BufferedReader`, который читает поток `System.in`

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Я так и имел в виду. Вы очень помогли